# Oracle Forms 11g Default Logon Screen

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

we verify the users of our application (in Oracle Forms 11g) using internal oracle database authentication. The user enters the user id, password and connection description in the default logon screen provided by Oracle Forms 11g (screenshot attached). When the user presses the CONNECT button in which trigger should I place the function to verify password constraints such as min password length etc in Oracle Forms?

your inputs will be much appreciated

thx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None, I presume.

This looks like the built-in logon form. It is supposed to accept credentials and - if they are valid - let you in. If it is, though, your own form which is VERY similar to the former, then you'd use either `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` (on the password item) or the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger (on the CONNECT button).

Password policy should be enforced elsewhere, for example in a form you use to create users and passwords, or - even better - within the **profile**. Have a look at the [CREATE PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6010.htm) command that also explains password parameters, one of which is the `PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION` you can use to enforce different conditions (such as minimum length, as you've said).

Answer (score 1):

You may get `username`, `password` or `connection_string` parameters' values for internal oracle database authentication screen by substituting them as argument of `get_application_property` method.

`ON-LOGON` and `ON_ERROR` triggers at form level may be used for you to manage your task :
[image]

*where* `ON-LOGON`*'s code text is* :

```
declare
  v_cnn    varchar2(35):='myDB';
begin 
    :global.v_lng := 6 ;
    :global.v_pwd := get_application_property(password);

    if ( length(:global.v_pwd) > :global.v_lng ) then   
    logon('myschema',:global.v_pwd||'@'||v_cnn);
    end if; 
end;
```

`ON-ERROR`*'s code text is* :

```
begin   
    if DBMS_Error_Code = -1017 then      
         :global.v_pwd := get_application_property(password);  
          if ( length(:global.v_pwd) < :global.v_lng ) then
           message('The length of the Password should be at least '||:global.v_lng||' characters !');   message('');      
          else  
           message(DBMS_Error_Text); message('');         
          end if;
    end if; 
end;
```

as an authentication example with certain minimum length for a schema's password.